# Detaching SBT not working

Tags: linux, scala, ubuntu, sbt, spray

Using SBT and SBT-revolver to run my Boot.scala using Spray, this works from command line:

```
    sbt -mem 12000 '~re-start'
```

However, this does not work:

```
    sbt -mem 12000 '~re-start' &
```

Why is this happening?

When I try to curl to my app's api routes, it does not appear listening. I do see this in my running processes though:

```
java -Xms12000m -Xmx12000m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m -jar /usr/local/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar ~re-start
```